# Encode Download Function

Tags: javascript, json, download, encode

When trying to download a set of [DICOM (Medical Image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) coordinates using JavaScript `encode` function. However, when we press the button that will handle the saving event, it opens a "**Save As:**" window asking us to save the file, but when we press "**Save**" it says:

> Failed - No file

For a more descriptive information of the issue the image is as follows:

[image]

We are using the [CORS (Allow-Control-Allow-Origin) plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) from [Google Chrome](https://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/chrome/browser/desktop/) and it might imply a wrong behaviour of the function. Just an idea of the issue.

This is the request code:

```
function download(data, name, type) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var url = new Blob([JSON.stringify({a: '1'}, null, 4)], {type: type});

    link.setAttribute( 'href', url );
    link.setAttribute( 'download', name );

    var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
    event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    link.dispatchEvent( event );
}
```

## Notes on Versions

- Google Chrome (v. 63.0.3239.132)
- Allow-Control-Allow-Origin (v. 1.0.3)
- macOS Sierra (v. 10.12.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`URL#createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL):

```js
function download(data, name, type) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify({a: '1'}, null, 4)], {type: type}));

    link.setAttribute( 'href', url );
    link.setAttribute( 'download', name );
}

download('data', 'name', 'text/plain');
```

```html
<a id="link">download</a>
```